# Search Irregularities

Tags: search, smartgroups, issues

We are on WP 4.9.4 and Civi 4.7.29 multisite.

There is incorrect behavior when trying to do a search on a smart group that is combining a activity type field and a custom field.

We have 750 search results when searching the custom field alone. We have 19 contacts in the activity field.

Therefore, you would expect at least 750 results when searching the smart group that combines the above fields. Instead, we get 124 results.

[image][image]

[image]

[image: smart group settings]

Here are the smart group settings.
Has anyone seen this kind of behavior?

Comment: have you tried via Search Builder? Have you ruled out that some Activities have multiple contacts on them?

Comment: I tried to replicate the search the smart group should be doing in search builder (as I originally created the group in adv search) but it also gives a much smaller size of contacts than what should be showing.